# Block WAN Access - Allow LAN Access - Linux hosts

Tags: networking, iptables

**What I am looking to do is block access to WAN and only allow these hosts to talk to each other on the 192.168.1.0/24 LAN. This configuration should be done on the hosts in question.**

There are some similar posts to this, but tend to be too specific use case, or overly complicated. I now pay for internet per/GB. I have certain VM's that don't really need WAN Access after being setup, but seem to be using large amounts of data. (LDAP Server for some reason?)

I'm looking into DD-WRT Filtering, but I wondered how to do this host side.

I will also be looking into enabling WAN Access for 1 hour daily. This could be done via "*iptables script*" with CRON, or just via DD-WRT.

I'm guessing IPTables is the way to go. I think all of my servers use IPTables, some have UFW and some have FirewallD.

I figure this can be a "generic question" with mostly answers that should work across many/all distros. But just to add, I'm mostly using Ubuntu 14/16 and CentOS 6/7.

Comment: Do you intend to do the configuration on VMs (or somewhere else)?

Comment: Yes via the CLI

Comment: Just to note, I ended up using DD-WRT w/ IP Range WAN Blocking Rules. It was much easier to setup, i now have IP Pools for WAN BLOCk, WAN BLOCK 23/7 and WAN ACCESS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Filtering with *IPTABLES*

This can be accomplished by creating a set of rules for allowed traffic and dropping the rest.

For the `OUTPUT` chain, create rules to accept loopback traffic and traffic to `192.168.1.0/24` network. Default action is applied when no rules are matched, set it to `REJECT`.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT REJECT
```

For `INPUT` chain, you can create similar rules. Allow traffic from loopback and local network, drop the rest.

You can match established traffic (reply traffic to connections initiated by your host) with a single rule using `-m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED`. This way you do not need to alter the chain when you want to enable Internet access. This works when you do not run any programs/daemons expecting connections from outside of your local network.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

If you need to allow connections initiated outside of your local network, you need to configure the `INPUT` chain in the same way as the `OUTPUT` chain and use similar mechanism to apply

To allow unrestricted (WAN access) network access, change the default action to `ACCEPT`. To put the limits back, change the default action back to `REJECT`. Same effect is achieved by adding/removing `-j ACCEPT` as last rule.

```
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

You can also use *iptables* *time* module to accept the traffic at specific time of a day, in which case you do not need to use cron. For example, to allow any outgoing traffic between 12:00 and 13:00 with following rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m time --timestart 12:00 --timestop 13:00 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I suggest to use REJECT for outgoing - DROP may stall processes running on the local servers.

Comment: +1 for using built in iptables timestop, will test soon and accept an answer, im leaning towards iptables. What would you use? IPTables or Default Gateway/Routing?

Comment: Do not use `-m state --state` because it deprecated. Use `-m conntrack --ctstate` instead

Answer (score 4):

### Removing the *default route*

When you remove the default route from your host's routing table, it prevents  it from communicating with other hosts outside the local network. Default route is configured with `ip route`: `ip route default add ...` to add the default route and `ip route del default` to remove it.

Traffic from your router might still be able to reach your host. You can discard traffic for which there is no known route to source address by enabling *reverse path filtering*.

There are two ways to configure reverse path filtering: *sysctl* or *iptables*. The *sysctl* method only applies to ipv4, iptables rule can be written for both both ipv4 and ipv6.

- To enable reverse path filtering using ***sysctl*** [`rp_filter`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt):

  ```
  sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
  ```
- With ***iptables***, using [`rpfilter`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbBX) module:

  ```
  iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -m rpfilter --invert -j DROP
  ```

  Same rule also works for `ip6tables`. For *nftables*, use [`fib`](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Routing_information) statement.

For removing and restoring the default route, you could use a simple script with cron:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
FILE="/root/default.gw"

case "$1" in
    "remove")
        route="$(ip route show default 0.0.0.0/0)"

        if [ -z "$route" ]; then
            echo "no default route configured"
            exit 1
        fi

        echo "$route" > $FILE
        ip route del default
        ip route flush cache
    ;;

    "restore")
        route="$(cat $FILE)"

        if [ -z "$route" ]; then
            echo "no default route saved"
            exit 1
        fi

        ip route add $route 
    ;;

    *)
        echo "invalid argument"
        echo "usage: $(basename -- $0) remove|restore"
        exit 1
esac
```