# Permanently disable all networking in Tails OS?

Tags: networking, security, configuration, tails-os

I would like to use Tails OS to create a *pseudo* air-gapped system. 
The system has WiFi hardware still, but it is "unusable" in Tails due to lack of firmware. I would like to further ensure it remains completely "unusable".

I'm aware of the manual option to "Disable all networking" on the greetings screen, but would like something more permanent.

The system does not have hardware switches to turn WiFi on / off.

I tried uninstalling networking packages, but the changes don't persist.

See [Defense in depth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)).

Comment: IMO If you want something more "Permanent and foolproof" you need to block internet access via a remote device or unhook the internet connection. Is this a VM or? I use DD-WRT Access Restrictions to block WAN access at home. You could look into IPTables of course >> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396218/block-wan-access-allow-lan-access-linux-hosts

Comment: If the system is already air-gapped, why is there a need to disable networking?  Is physical access to the system restricted?  Does the system have WiFi?  If it does have Wifi, is there a hardware switch (if laptop) or the ability to remove the network card (if desktop) or disable onboard network via BIOS? ... If physical access is not restricted, then the air-gapped system is easily compromised anyway...

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question to make the goal more clear.

Comment: There are a few possible answers to this question... one is to create a udev rule to disable all wireless interfaces upon connection, substituting `KERNEL=="wlan*"` in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment/63237) ... another possible answer is to disable the WiFi through the BIOS (should be an option if onboard) ... another answer is to open the laptop case (presumed laptop, but the question should specify) and remove the WiFi module (usually possible) ...  But, with physical access, none of it matters.

Comment: @RubberStamp Will these udev rules persist in TailsOS?  It is not totally clear to me what is being substituted with `KERNEL=="wlan*"` -- is it `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"` ?